# I created a ListView UserControl but after dragging it to the form1 designer when adding items to it i see nothing why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There two strange things.
First now I marked not to use the columns I marked // not to add the Columns.
Before when I used the Columns it was working fine but now after not using them it's showing like it's adding items to the ListView but in fact there is nothing in the ListView it's empty.

First the UserControl of the ListView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Searcher
{
    public partial class ListViewCostumControl : UserControl
    {
        public static ListViewControl lvnf;

        public ListViewCostumControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListViewControl();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.Details;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            //lvnf.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            //lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
            //lvnf.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
            lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
            lvnf.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public class ListViewControl : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewControl()
            {
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is how i'm using it in form1.
The strange thing in form1 when I srag the ListView from the toolbox I see:

listViewCostumControl1 but when trying to use it in form1 when I type:
listViewCostumControl1. there are no properties like Items.
What I need to do in form1 is:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.BeginUpdate();
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add("Directory: " + lblCurrentDirectory.Text + "In File: " + lblStatus.Text + l[i]);
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Invalidate();
```

But shouldn't it be that I will use the listViewCostumControl1 with the properties like Items.Add and BeginUpdate ?

Not what a mess I did here.
It seems what i'm dragging in form1 designer is not what i'm using in the form1 code.

What should I change/do to make the UserControl of the ListView control to work like any other control I drag in the designer from the toolbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wher are my items?

When you set a listView to show in `Details` mode, it shows the items only if it has some columns. So when you don't add columns, it doesn't show any column.

To solve the problem, you can add columns or set the `View` property to another view like `List`, `SmallIcon`, ... .

> Where is Items property?

You inherited from `UserControl` and it doesn't have an `Items` property.

To solve the problem, if you need a custom list view, directly inherit from `ListView` and not from `UserControl`. Then when you use the custom list view, you can see all `ListView` properties like `Items`.